# django app consuming rest api - where to put the code

Tags: django, boto

I have an django app, a model which stores data entered via a web interface by a user.

I need to consume an third party REST api when viewing / saving a model instance. I know how to do this but, what I am unsure about is where this code should live with the django app.

my gut is to put this code with in the model class, but then you could also use a view... I am just not sure.

How has this been done before, there are lots of posts asking how to do this, but none stating best place to put the code.

any guidance would be gratefully received.

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a subjective question, so here is a subjective answer.

First of all, ensure that any code that interacts with this external REST API resides in a separate module. E.g, if you're grabbing word definitions from a dictionary API, all the code that talks to this API should ideally be in a separate `dictionary` module, which you can then import into your view.

Secondly, your `models.py` should merely declare your application's data model and define the operations on this model, and little else. They should not be concerned with request/response cycles, reading files, rendering templates, making HTTP calls, or anything else. By this logic, you should be making these REST API calls from your views and, if required, passing the returned data into your models.

And finally, think twice about making REST calls from your Django app. Python does synchronous (blocking) I/O by default, which means as long the app is waiting for the REST call to finish, it can't service any incoming HTTP requests. This is not an issue if you don't have too many users, but it's something to keep in mind for apps that need to scale. You might want to look into async I/O libraries for Python.

Comment: hello, thanks very much for your reply. it has cleared up my questions about what goes in models vs views. good points about async, i am looking at django-celery and some sort of ajax